# Android previous fragment blank screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity. This activity check if the user is already logged in or not. If the user already logged in the activity show the LoginFragment. If the user login from the LoginFragment its showin the MainFragment and from the MainFragment user can go to the SettingsFragment.
But if I press the back button on SettingsFragment, it loads a blank fragment.

I use this method for "fragment navigation":

```
public void showFragment(String fragmentName){
    Fragment fragment = null;
    boolean backstack = true;
    if (fragmentName.equals(SysKeys.MAIN_FRAGMENT)){
        fragment = new MainFragment();
    } else if (fragmentName.equals(SysKeys.LOGIN_FRAGMENT)){
        fragment = new LoginFragment();
        backstack = false;
    } else if (fragmentName.equals(SysKeys.SETTINGS_FRAGMENT)){
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
    } else if (fragmentName.equals(SysKeys.CUSTOM_LOGIN_FRAGMENT)){
        fragment = new CustomLoginFragment();
    }

    if (fragment != null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_right, R.anim.slide_out_to_left, R.anim.slide_in_from_left, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_layout, fragment, fragmentName);
        if (backstack){
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

I don't want to backstack the LoginFragment, but the others i would like. What is wrong with my code or logic?

UPDATE:
Now it not show the LoginFragment if I press back button on the MainFragment, but sometimes it just reload the MainFragment if I press the back button.
Here is the code:

```
public void showFragment(String fragmentName){
    Fragment fragment = null;
    boolean backstack = true;
    if (fragmentName.equals(SysKeys.MAIN_FRAGMENT)){
        fragment = new MainFragment();
        backstack = false;
    } else if (fragmentName.equals(SysKeys.LOGIN_FRAGMENT)){
        fragment = new LoginFragment();
        backstack = false;
    } else if (fragmentName.equals(SysKeys.SETTINGS_FRAGMENT)){
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
    } else if (fragmentName.equals(SysKeys.CUSTOM_LOGIN_FRAGMENT)){
        fragment = new CustomLoginFragment();
    }

    if (fragment != null){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_right, R.anim.slide_out_to_left, R.anim.slide_in_from_left, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_layout, fragment, fragmentName);
        if (backstack){
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: add other fragments into the backstack but do not add the login fragment into the backstack

Comment: once you make your backstack = false....when are you making it true again? Please try by making backstack = true for fragments other then Login Fragment.

Comment: @ShadowDroid in showFragment method at the second line I set backstack = true

Comment: @stacyqueen I have tried this without much success...

Comment: then remove this 
fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: I removed this, but now its show me the LoginFragment if I press the back button on the MainFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every time you show the fragment, you already the pop the previous backstack. Why must you do that?
Try to remove `fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`

Also set backstack = false when you create MainFragment, So it'll not add MainFragment to backstack and you will finhish activity when press back from MainFragment

 Hope this helps.

Comment: I removed the fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); line, but now if I login on the LoginFragment and app go the MainFragment and i press the back button it shows the LoginFragment, but I don't want to see this

Comment: @user3275938 also set backstack = false when you create MainFragment, So it'll not add MainFragment to backstack and you will finhish activity when press back from MainFragment

Comment: Thanks! Now its working, but sometimes if I on the MainFragment, and press the back button, it reload the MainFragment, why?
I updated my question with the new code

Comment: @user3275938, Sorry, I don't know why that, Do you override onBackPress? Is there a case that user go direct to MainFrag without go to LoginFrag?When Activity create, you add fragment by code or already have a fragment in layout? beside, you should add log in showFragment with name and backstack to make sure you don't accident call showFragment twice, Also check to make sure you don't add the backstack some where else. There are many case can lead to this issue. And I don't think it's because of the code in showFragment.

Comment: Now its okay! I had to do a Clean on the project and now it is working!
Thank you very much! Please write your comment as answer, and i will accept it.